# Is it necessary to rebuild all the binaries that is using a class inside a binary with virtual function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, binary, virtual-functions

I have a binary ABC.dll which is having a class A having virtual functions inside it.

**ABC.dll**

```
class A
{
    /* variables*/
    public:
    virtual func1(int x, int y, int z);
    /* other member functions and virtual functions*/
}
```

There are other binaries as well which are creating object of this class and using its members.

eg **LIB.dll**

```
A *obj = new A(/* constructor arguments*/);
```

and other dlls as well which are using this class.

Now my software has ABC.dll, LIB.dll and all other dlls and the software is working fine as expected.
Note that the virtual function that I have above is not called anywhere in any other binaries.

Now I need to change function definition of the virtual function to add a parameterized variable to it.

```
class A
{
    /* variables*/
    public:
    virtual func1(int x, int y, int z, int newVal = 0);
    /* other member functions and virtual functions*/
}
```

So after making this change here, do I need to build all other binaries which are using this `class A` or building just this binary would work?

Since my code base is large its difficult to go through every project and find the places where its currently used.

If I need to build all those dll again which were using this `class A` and replace it on my software location then what's the reason for it.

Problem currently : The process is crashing which is using this dll currently if I am not building the dependents and replacing them in my software.

Would the case be same if it was a non virtual function?

**Note :** I made changes in that dll as well which was implementing this virtual function

Comment: You are changing public API so you have to rebuild everything! If you do an inheritance between dll-s then even adding virtual function needs rebuild everything.

Comment: However earlier when I wasn't using any virtual function, the process was not crashing for the software

Comment: The public API that I was talking(func1) about is not used anywhere in other dlls currently.

Comment: virtual or not in this case it doesn't matter. You are adding extra argument so you have to rebuild everything. Default value means that compiler will add missing value silently, and function always need 4 arguments.

Comment: but the thing is that the function which I changes is not been called anywhere else in other dlls

Answer (score 1):

When you change prototype of any function you are breaking binary compatibility. It doesn't meater if function is virtual or not.

Providing default value for extra argument lets you maintain source compatibility, but it breaks binary compatibility. Default value for arguments means that if compiler sees call of that function with missing argument, he has to implcicitly add to calling code this extra argument with default value. This means rebuild of caller is needed.

Now since you are modifying a function which is virtual then there is no choice you have to rebuild everything.
If this function wouldn't be virtual then you could provide an overload so old prototype would remain valid.
For virtual functions: adding, removing or changing API or even changing order of it, breaks binary compatibility. That is why overload can't come to the rescue.

Comment: My doubt is the caller dll is anyway calling it with 3 argument, then why exactly does it need to be built again

Comment: I also understood what you were trying to say but don't you think there is one another problem as well, since in other dlls which are using the virtualfunc will be having vptr and vtable and the address of the function definition `func1(int x, int y, int z)` but now since we changed it, vtable also needs to be changed as the function defintion has changed to `func1(int x, int y, int z, int newVal = 0);`  and hence its address as well, as the address are decided during the compile time

Comment: Again default value doesn't have impact on what function is exported from dll. Function is always called with all arguments. Default value instructs compiler to add missing argument when function is called.

Comment: So do you mean like the other dll where I am calling this function, over there itself the funcion will be called with default parameter value. for rg if the call is made as `func1(1,2,3)` in other dll then compiler will itself add `func1(1,2,3,0) `where 0 is the default values while calling this function?

Comment: See how default value works here: https://cppinsights.io/s/e86fefce

Comment: cool got it, but in my case this function where I made my change was not getting called anywhere, just other functions where no change was made was being called by creating object of this class

Comment: please reply, for the above doubt

Comment: i guess even if u r not using that func where u made change still u need to rebuild all binaries, right @MarekR ? But I too don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Changing the function in A changes it's signature / location in the binary so likely your dependent lib now tries to execute the function from the incorrect offset as it was not relinked to know where the function in A now resides.